# ANT how to fork task execution?

Tags: ant, fork, task

I need to fork a new process for a specific ant task. I dont see a fork attribute in the taskdef how do I do it ?

I should be clearer, I am not talking about executing ANT in a forked process:

I have an ant task X, which I need to run in a forked process. Its some third party task which i use with taskdef X and then use this way

Is there anyway to tell any that anytime i use that task please fork the process and run ?

Answer (score 3):

See [Running Ant via Java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava) in the Ant manual.